# Django template: How to pass formatted string to include tag

Tags: django, django-templates

I am new to Django and Django template, I know Django Template is kind of restrictive compare to Rails.

So I am including a template in email like:

```
{% include "./partials/_info_row.html" with value=f'{request_count} requests' %}
```

but this throws error: `TemplateSyntaxError: Could not parse the remainder: ''{request_count} requests'' from 'f'{request_count} requests''`

Is there a way to pass formatted string like this to include tag?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Exception is raised because you can't use f-strings in Django templates - templates language is not actually a Python.
According to [doc's](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/templates/builtins/#include) there is not need to explicitly pass context variable when using `include`:

> Loads a template and renders it with the current context.

If you need to pass a combined value (context plus something else like "requests" string), you can use [simple tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/custom-template-tags/#simple-tags):

**tags.py**

```
@register.simple_tag(takes_context=True)
def your_custom_tag(context, format_string):
    request_count = context['request_count']
    return f'{request_count} requests'
```

**templates**

```
{% with r_count=your_custom_tag %}
{% include "./partials/_info_row.html" with value=r_count %}
```

Comment: Is there a way to use `pluralize` in custom templatetags? currently I have to write `if else` to add `s` if count is greater than 1

Answer (score 1):

```
{% include "./partials/_info_row.html" with value=request_count|stringformat:'s'|add:' requests' %}
```

1. request_count|stringformat:'s' - convert number to string
2. some_var|add:'requests' - concat strings

Comment: The `stringformat` solution seems to work, but can I pluralize the string based on `request_count`?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Chamel and @crazyzuber. I used combination of your answers. Created custom filter.

I knew about custom tag. But I wanted to avoid that because this was not generic tag, it will get used only at one place, so I wanted a solution for which I dont have to write custom tag. But custom tags solution works because it allows you to format string in anyway, which was not possible using existing built-in.

Btw I used `@register.filter`

```
@register.filter(is_safe=True)
def request_count_text(count):
    return f"{count} request{ 's' if count > 1 else '' }"
```

and using it as:

```
{% include "./_info_row.html" with value=request_count|request_count_text %}
```

This solves my issue.